# Instruments alleges Memory leak with [UIColor CGColor]

Tags: ipad, memory-management, memory-leaks, uicolor, cgcolor

I am just in the process of tracking down some memory leaks with Instruments. It claims I am leaking in the middle of a drawRect method. Here is the code:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (highColor && lowColor) {
        // Set the colors for the gradient to the two colors specified for high and low

        // The next line is allegedly leaking
        [gradientLayer setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)[highColor CGColor], (id)[lowColor CGColor], nil]]; 
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.2);
    }

    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

I am on the iPad, so I have to manage the memory myself (that is, no garbage collection). Can anyone see what's wrong here? My understanding is that I don't have to release the array nor should I have to release the CGColors. Also, is there any way in Instruments to find out what object type is leaking, ie. is it referring to the NSArray or the CGColors?

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you.

PS: I got the code for the GradientView from somewhere some months ago; it works very well (other than exposing the aforementioned memory leak). You can find the code [here](http://www.cimgf.com/2010/01/28/fun-with-uibuttons-and-core-animation-layers/).

EDIT:

I have done a bit more research and refactored my code as follows:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    if (highColor && lowColor) {
        // The following two lines are leaking
        CGColorRef highCGColor = [highColor CGColor];
        CGColorRef lowCGColor = [lowColor CGColor];

        // Set the colors for the gradient to the two colors specified for high and low
        [gradientLayer setColors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)highCGColor, (id)lowCGColor, nil]];
        gradientLayer.startPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.2);

        CGColorRelease(highCGColor);
        CGColorRelease(lowCGColor);
    }

    [super drawRect:rect];
}
```

However, I can't work out why the two CGColors are still leaking. I am releasing them at the end of the method. Is it possible that the NSArray does not release them properly when it is deallocated? Still puzzled...

Answer (score 0):

I´m not an expert with memory managment on iphone/ipad, but the way I would do it:
try with an NSAutoreleasepool in your if, the pool then handles the memory managment, so you have to:

```
if...
NSAutoreleasePool *mypool=[[NSAutoreleasePool alloc]init];
...
[mypool drain];
```

Try it out and see if there is still a leakage, but remember not to delete your 2 rows where you release your colors.

Comment: As it turns out I actually have to delete the two rows where I release my colours. They are wrong as I do not own the two colours according to the CoreFoundation memory management rules.

Answer (score 0):

How are highColor and lowColor declared within your UIView? Are they being appropriately released / autoreleased?  How about the declaration of your gradientLayer object, is that being released appropriately?  Here is some code that I used at one stage to create a gradient on a UIView. Instead of using layers it draws directly into the current context. Perhaps it might help:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    CGGradientRef myGradient;
    CGColorSpaceRef myColorSpace;
    size_t num_locations = 3;
    CGFloat locations[3] = {0.0, 0.5, 1.0};
    CGFloat components[12] = {0.855, 0.749, 0.196, 1.0,
                              0.973, 0.933, 0.267, 1.0,
                              0.855, 0.749, 0.196, 1.0};
    myColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    myGradient = CGGradientCreateWithColorComponents(myColorSpace, components, locations, num_locations);

    CGPoint myStartPoint, myEndPoint;
    myEndPoint.x = self.bounds.size.width;

    CGContextDrawLinearGradient(context, myGradient, myStartPoint, myEndPoint, 0);

    CGColorSpaceRelease(myColorSpace);
    CGGradientRelease(myGradient);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be releasing highCGColor and lowCGColor.